# jQuery: Fade out siblings

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, meteor

using mizzao:bootstrap-3 and mizzao:jquery-ui.

There are two divs displayed on the page. Each with a heading. This is where the user decides which user type they are. When the user selects (clicks) one, I would like the OTHER div to fadeout of view.

Right now I am fading out the div that I click on.

If I put a class into the a tag, will the other a tag be its sibling?

There is styling to the div keep in mind in .css
client.js

```
Template.authJoinType.events({
'click div.join-type-heading': function(e, tmpl) {
 $('div.join-type-heading').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<template name="authJoinType">
 <div class="container join-type">
    <div class="row"> 


        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#">
            <div class="join-type-heading"  value="reader">Reader</div>
        </a>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#">
            <div class="join-type-heading"  value="publisher">Publisher
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery not function. It'll help you. Here I've updated with plain jquery.

```
    $('div.join-type-heading').on('click',function() {

    $('.join-type-heading').not(this).each(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
// $(this).slideUp();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h59sG/41/

http://jsfiddle.net/h59sG/42/

Comment: This is not yet functioning. I replaced the .animate({"left": "0", "top": "0"}); with .fadeOut("slow"); to check and it fades both of them out.

Comment: He is able to fade out both div using the mentioned animate. If so, then this should be possible..

Comment: Check the latest one. I've updated with plain jquery. Is it helpfull to you ? If not please reply.

Comment: YES!! This is perfect Jeeva! May I ask for one extra thing...as these divs are sitting side by side, can I animate it so once clicked, the remaining div glides to the left(this will be if the right ones remains of course)?
SOmthing like slides.css({ 'float' : 'left' });

Comment: I've checked your div. You are using bootstrap. And your divs are sitting side by side. Now you want to move the div to the left which are not clicked. Right ?

Comment: I won't say the following is the good example. But can you check this ? It'll give you an idea to help you out from this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/h59sG/43/

Comment: It's close, I like the original fadeOut, just somehow trying to add code so the remaining div glides to a left position.

Comment: If you see the jQuery without bootstrap, it does the move left by default. http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-GfjC6/1/5?curriculum_id=50a3fad8c7a770b5fd0007a1